# Decoding a binary file

Tags: android

I am using the following code to read a structured binary file

```
FileInputStream objIS = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/waverider.usr");

DataInputStream objBR = new DataInputStream(objIS);
objwVer = objBR.readShort();
objwSVer = objBR.readShort();
objNoWaypoints = objBR.readShort();

System.out.println(objwVer);
System.out.println(objwSVer);
System.out.println(objNoWaypoints);
objIS.close();
```

This produces the result:
512
0
8706

The result I am after is
2
0
546

That is what I get with VB.net using:

```
objwVer = objBR.ReadInt16
objwSVer = objBR.ReadInt16
objNoWaypoints = objBR.ReadInt16
```

The binary file is as follow:

02 00 00 00 22 02 00 00 4b a9 c8 ff b2 2d 33 00

00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 48 6f 6d 65 00 00 00 00

1c 68 53 0d 10 27 00 00 00 00 01 00 7e 8c c8 ff

Am I missing something here
9d 33 33 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that
your file is written in little endian [byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) but your code is expecting big endian byte order.

Answer (score 0):

Your stream is encoded in little-endian and `DataInputStream` only supports big-endian.

You could use [ByteBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) instead, which allows to parse little-endian formatted stream: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#LITTLE_ENDIAN

Comment: Thank you I used
byte[]buffer7=new byte[4];
byte[]buffer8=new byte[2];

objBR.read(buffer7);
objBR.read(buffer8);

long WaypointNameLength =
ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer7).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
System.out.println(WaypointNameLength); 
char WaypointNameChar1 =
ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getChar();
System.out.println(WaypointNameChar1);

WaypointNameLength gives the correct result 4
WaypointNameChar1 gives wrong result. it should be H
In the Binary file the 2 Byte value is 48 which is the Ascii value of H
Where am I still going wrong

Comment: I am getting some Chinese letter as a result

Answer (score 0):

try [JBBP framework](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/), it is android compatible and its JBBPBitInputStream allows read data in different byte and bit order

```
new JBBPBitInputStream(in).readInt(JBBPByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```